# Как отобразить результат выполнения метода в родителе при использовании super в Java

Tags: java

```
public class Tax {

    int numberOfDepends;
    double grossIncome;
    String state;

    public double calcTax(){    // отобразить результат этого метода

        if(grossIncome < 50000){
            return grossIncome * 0.06; 
        }
        else {
            return grossIncome * 0.08; 
        }
    }
}   

public class NjTax extends Tax {

    public double adjustForStudents(double tax){
    return tax - 500;
    }

    public double calcTax(){

        super.calcTax();

        if(grossIncome < 50000){
            return grossIncome * 0.10;  
        }  
        else {
            return grossIncome * 0.13;
        }
    }
}

public class TestTax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    NjTax t = new NjTax();

    t.grossIncome = 40000;
    t.numberOfDepends = 2;
    t.state = "NY";

    double yourTax = t.calcTax();
    double njt = t.adjustForStudents(yourTax);

    System.out.println("Your tax is " + njt);
   }
}
```

Comment: Вывести в консоль?

Comment: double result=super.calcTax(); System.out.println(result);

Comment: Да, вывести в консоль

Comment: double result=super.calcTax(); System.out.println(result); в методе main не работает  - "Cannot use super in a static context"

Answer (score -1):

Ваш код может быть реализован, но, как я понял, вы пытаетесь вызвать результат из статического контекста главного метода, в чем и заключается проблема. Проинициализировав все правильно проблема уйдет. (Кстати, мой код от вашего мало чем отличается.)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Main main = new Main();
        NjTax tax = main.createNjTax();
        double res = tax.calcTax();
        System.out.println( "Not super calc=" + res );
    }

    public NjTax createNjTax() {
        NjTax tax = new NjTax();
        tax.numberOfDepends = 1;
        tax.grossIncome = 2;
        return tax;
    }
}

class Tax {

    int numberOfDepends;
    double grossIncome;
    String state;

    public double calcTax(){
        return grossIncome < 50000 ? grossIncome * 0.06 : grossIncome * 0.08;
    }
}

class NjTax extends Tax {

    public double adjustForStudents(double tax){
        return tax - 500;
    }

    public double calcTax(){
        double res = super.calcTax();
        System.out.println( "Super calc=" + res );
        return grossIncome < 50000 ? grossIncome * 0.10 : grossIncome * 0.13;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Я так понимаю, что пример моего кода не может быть реализован. Хотелось бы понять можно ли его представить тогда более изящно и правильно?

Comment: Да я вызываю через main. Проблема действительно в том, что реализация вроде бы есть но вывода нет. Буду разбирать ваш код. Хочу дойти к пониманию реализации своего...